# How to find the original address of a file from dynamic URL?

Tags: download, url

In some cases, when you want to download a file from a website, you can't see the original address of the file. for example look this URL:

[image]

How can I find the direct URL of the file?

Is there any approach or program to find the original(direct) URL?

Answer (score 1):

In most of those cases there isn't a "direct URL" of the file. Either the file will be created dynamically or it is located in a directory that isn't accessible via an url. A script (here download.do) reads the file and passes the content through to the requesting browser.

Comment: Thanks, In fact, I want to leech it by this site: http://rapid.iophim.com/index.php but I can't leech it. I think this subject is related to Cookies. are you agree with me? in your opinion, How can I solve this problem?